# Set title from controller/codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to set the page title from the controller, and if so how is it done?

Thanks
M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suggest is that you create a public property on your class and reference the property from the view page.

In your controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.Title = "My Title";

        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<head>      
    <title><%= this.Title %></title>  
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply add the title to the `ViewBag` and then display it in your view:

in controller:

```
ViewBag.PageTitle = "Your Page Title";
```

In the view/layout

```
 <head>
    <title>@ViewBag.PageTitle</title>
</head>
```

This is based on Razor's syntax, but works equally fine with the class ASPX syntax as well.

Comment: Is this the only way? I really would like to just write something in the controller that makes the change.. But that might be against MVC?

Comment: Is there something in particular about this method that bothers you?

Comment: I have a master page and the update should be done in another page, I only like to update the title once and there should be a "standard" title for the master page. Just felt it could be easier if there was a simple line in codebehind to write.

Comment: How do you set your title in the Master page now?  The way I typically do it is I'll have `<title>@ViewBag.Title ?? "Some default title"</title>` in my layout (master) page - this way I have an easy way to set individual page titles from the controller, but if I don't set it (`ViewBag.Title` is null) "Some default title" would be displayed.  Personally I can't really think of an MVC-based solution that would make this any easier.

Comment: Hmm, could you please stat the exact code for this solution because cant get it working with our without <%%>

Comment: It would be the same on the controller side, but in the View you'd do `<%= ViewBag.Title ?? "Default Title" %>`.  If this doesn't work, would you mind posting some of your View code?